# System.PlatformNotSupported Exception in Dot Net Core XML load and transform with XSLT having VB script

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, .net-core

I am trying to transform xml using xslt having script but not able as code is throwing platform not supported exception with message Compiling JScript/CSharp scripts is not supported. Does dot net core support xml xslt transform with vb script? I am using 2.1 dot net core.

My code is :

```cs
XslCompiledTransform xslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xmlfile))
{
    using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
    {
        xslTransform.Load(xr, XsltSettings.TrustedXslt, myResolver);
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand from https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/19837, there is no support for embedded "script" calls with `ms:script` inside the XSLT but you should be able to use extension objects to call any .NET framework function as done in https://github.com/brandonh-msft/EmbeddedXsltTestFunction/blob/master/EmbeddedXsltTestFunction/Function1.cs. So you would need to move any VB code out of the XSLT and implement/wrap it as an extension object you pass with an XsltArgumentList to the `Transform` method. And it is JScript.NET or C# or VB.NET support you get, not VBScript.

Comment: Thanks Martin - I tried the way you told . I converted my VB Script functions in C# but I am getting an exception while transforming . Exception is - 
Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespace '{nameof(XSLTFunctions)}'. 
I have written this namespace in separate XSLT file.

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" version="1.0"  xmlns:vb="{nameof(XSLTFunctions)}">

Comment: You will need to edit your question and provide minimal but complete samples to allow us to reproduce the problem. From that snippet in a comment it is hard to tell what you tried and where it got wrong. Did you see the `$` sign with the string literal containing the XSLT code? That means in the linked example the `{nameof(XSLTFunctions)}` is evaluated and the final XSLT is computed in the C# code.

Comment: If you write an external XSLT document use your own URI e.g. `xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"` in the XSLT and then `mf:foo()` to call a function in that namespace and `xsltArgList.AddExtensionObject("http://example.com/mf", yourCSharpObjectOrClass)`.

Comment: Martin - After your last comment, I worked on setting URI of external XSLT. I set the C# script class name on run time by setting element attribute. it did what we wanted. really appreciate your help. I get some time I will post my own answer mentioning your approach. Big Thank You . +1

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This answer is taken from the top-level comments on this question and [this github repo](https://github.com/brandonh-msft/EmbeddedXsltTestFunction) (which is linked in the comments). I just pulled everything together in an answer to make it easier for future readers.

You can use extension objects to call your own C# methods from XSLT.

For example, define the methods you want to use:

```cs
public class XsltFunctions
{
    public static string ToLower(XPathNodeIterator iterator)
    {
        return iterator.OfType<XPathNavigator>().FirstOrDefault()?.Value.ToLower();
    }
}
```

Then register that class as an extensions object when running your XSLT. (Pay attention to the `AddExtensionObject` method.)

```cs
public string RunXslt(string inputXml)
{
    // xml transform pointing to custom code
    var xsltDocumentString = $@"<xsl:stylesheet version=""1.0"" xmlns:xsl=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"" xmlns:msxsl=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"" xmlns:user=""{nameof(XsltFunctions)}""> 
    <xsl:template match=""MyElt"">
<MyElt>
    <OriginalValue>
        <xsl:copy-of select=""node()""/>
    </OriginalValue>
    <ToLowerValue>
        <xsl:value-of select=""user:ToLower(node())""/>
    </ToLowerValue>
</MyElt>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>";

    // Compile the style sheet.
    var xslt_settings = new XsltSettings();
    var xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
    var styleSheetReader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xsltDocumentString));
    xslt.Load(styleSheetReader, xslt_settings, new XmlUrlResolver());

    // Add capability to ref external functions
    var xsltArgList = new XsltArgumentList();
    xsltArgList.AddExtensionObject(nameof(XsltFunctions), new XsltFunctions());

    // Load the XML source file.
    XmlReader inputDataReader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(inputXml));

    // Create an XmlWriter.
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
    settings.Indent = true;

    var output = new StringBuilder();
    var writer = new XmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(output));

    // Execute the transformation.
    xslt.Transform(inputDataReader, xsltArgList, writer);

    // return the transformed XML response to the caller
    return output.ToString();
}
```

Tested in .NET Core 2.1 and .NET 5, using the following NUnit test.

```cs
[Test]
public void RunXsltWithExternalFunctions()
{
    // Arrange.
    var inputXml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<MyXml>
    <MyElt>
        MyEltValue
    </MyElt>
</MyXml>";

    // Act.
    var outputXml = RunXslt(inputXml);

    // Assert.
    Assert.That(outputXml, Does.Contain("myeltvalue"));
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/brandonh-msft/EmbeddedXsltTestFunction)

See also: [XSLT Extension Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xslt-extension-objects)

Comment: This was the right solution for me. I had to change this part xmlns:user="{nameof(XsltFunctions)}" in the xslt template to xmlns:user=""{XsltFunctions}"" but I may have some other flaws in my code that caused my a problem here. Thanks!